# Prevent included htm page from being loaded outside of parent php page

Tags: php, include, parent-child

I have a page thisfile.htm, which is included in thisfile.php

I used to load thisfile.htm into an iframe on thisfile.php but because of iPad scrolling trouble, I recently converted everything to scrolling divs and php includes.

I need to prevent the htm file from being loaded independently of the php parent. When I used iframes, I had no problem doing this with some javascript. But I can't get it to work with my php include - I get a loop.

This is in child:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if(top.location.href==self.location.href) {

location.replace("thisfile.php");

}

</script>
```

This is in parent:

```
<div class="bigdiv"><?php include "thisfile.htm" ?></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I need to prevent the htm file from being loaded independently of the php parent" - For what reason? A Javascript check can be easily circumvented. Also, you should be able to do a more solid check in PHP. For example, define a constant in thisfile.php and check if the same constant is set in a PHP version of your html file.

Comment: Also, I don't think the javascript code will do what you want. Effectively, top is usually used in the context of frames referring to the topmost window and becomes window if there are no frames. What it is most likely doing is changing the location which in turn reloads the page which loads the same javascript again. This is where your loop is coming from.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `include` in php, the easiest way to protect the file you are including, is to place it outside of the web-root. That way php can get to it, but a browser can´t so it can never be loaded separately. You don´t need any javascript in the child if you do it like this.

Comment: +1 Just what I was typing, but I was too slow because of watching the 962th rerun of Married with Children. ;)

Comment: The htm pages are old names and have high google rankings and the client wanted to avoid losing that rank. Maybe I should just do some 301s.

Comment: I understand there's more than one such file? You can try to 301 some of them, while keeping the others available for a while. Then in a few days, you can see what effect it has had on those pages. If Google has picked up the 301 correctly, you can 301 the others too. This way, you will prevent a sudden drop in page ranking (though probably temporarily) on the entire site.

Comment: Perhaps you could have meta refresh tags in those pages to redirect to new pages. That way the potential traffic can be redirected. I've seen a few sites avoiding the issue of having fixed references through url rewriting.

Comment: UPDATE. Their host will not allow htaccess. Y! Any other suggestions?

Comment: @amy If you can get the host to process `.htm` files as php files you can use headers in your `.htm` files: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

If thisfile.htm is to be included in a div in thisfile.php, just include it in php, using `include`. You don't have to call thisfile.htm from the outside at all. In fact, you could place it outside your doc root, in which case you cannot reach it from outside at all. It will only be included in thisfile.php.